# Am I able to create a taxonomy/term/%/x view path using the term alias?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have enabled the built in taxonomy/term/% view

I have created a display with path /taxonomy/term/%/test

I also have a URL alias setup on the taxonomy/term path to be /fruits/apple

So I would expect this to work /fruits/apple/test would display my view.

When I browse to this path I get Page not found.

If I browse to the un-aliased path ie /taxonomy/term/156/test it works.

Should the alias work like this?

Ive tried every combination I can think of. Reenabled the view, created new displays, removed all other displays etc

Comment: I think you need to see [Create view with path relative to taxonomy term](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263191/create-view-with-path-relative-to-taxonomy-term)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Path redirect](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect). If itsn't help, [rewrite engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_rewrite) help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [sub-pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module.

> This module extends that behavior by also matching known sub-paths and
>   replacing them with their respective alias.
>
> For example, if user/1 is aliased to users/admin, this module rewrites
>   the link to the user contact page user/1/contact to use the aliased
>   URL users/admin/contact instead.